# String parsing with Python

Tags: python, string, parsing

I can't seem to find any docs on the parse() method for strings.  Is there a good reference?  I want to parse the following:

```
frame 0 rows {3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 4 3 3 4 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 4 3 4 3 3 3 3 4 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 3 2 4 3 4 3 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 3 4 4 3 3 3 4 4 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 4} columns {2 3 2 3 3 3 4 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 4 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 4 4 3 4 4 3 3 4 3 5 5 5 5 4 5 4 4 4}
```

into two lists of int.

Comment: That's not what `string.parse()` is designed to be used for (it's used internally as part of `string.format()`). Try taking a look at the `re` regular expressions library instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python strings' parse() won't help you here (it has a very obscure use).  In this case, I'd do it the obvious way: With regexes!  If 's' is your string above,

```
import re
lists = [
    [int(i) for i in match.split()]
    for match in re.findall(r'{(.*?)}', s)
]

print lists
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a="frame 0 rows {3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 4 3 3 4 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 4 3 4 3 3 3 3 4 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 3 2 4 3 4 3 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 3 4 4 3 3 3 4 4 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 4} columns {2 3 2 3 3 3 4 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 4 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 4 4 3 4 4 3 3 4 3 5 5 5 5 4 5 4 4 4}"

>>> import ast
>>> import re
>>> for match in re.finditer("\{([\d ]+)\}",a):
    integers=match.groups()[0]
    l=ast.literal_eval(integers.replace(" ",","))
    print l


(3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4)
```

I have never heard of a parse method to actually parses the string in the way you ask. However, parsing that string is not that hard. Here is how to do it.

Comment: Why are you using `ast` here?

Comment: @Senthil: There is no good reason to use it in this particular case. Just calling `int()` like in Jesse's answer is probably more efficient and right way to do it.

Comment: @funktu: Thanks for the answer anyway as I am still not familiar with ast, and it's good to some examples of its use.

Answer (score 1):

For such nicely structured data, pyparsing may be more than you need, but it makes for a good tutorial example:

```
from pyparsing import *

s = "frame 0 rows {3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 4 3 3 4 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 4 3 4 3 3 3 3 4 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 3 2 4 3 4 3 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 3 4 4 3 3 3 4 4 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 4} columns {2 3 2 3 3 3 4 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 4 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 4 4 3 4 4 3 3 4 3 5 5 5 5 4 5 4 4 4}"

LBRACE,RBRACE = map(Suppress,"{}")
integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))

line = ("frame" + integer("frame") + 
        "rows" + LBRACE + ZeroOrMore(integer)("rows") + RBRACE + 
        "columns" + LBRACE + ZeroOrMore(integer)("columns") + RBRACE )

data = line.parseString(s)
print data.frame
print data.rows[:10]
print data.columns[:10]
```

prints:

```
0
[3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

type pydoc -p 5000 into the command line
then got to http://localhost:5000/string.html#Formatter-parse

Answer (score 0):

```
m_string = "frame 0 rows {3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 4 3 3 4 3 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 4 3 4 3 3 3 3 4 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 3 2 4 3 4 3 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 3 4 4 3 3 3 4 4 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 4} columns {2 3 2 3 3 3 4 3 3 2 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 4 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 4 4 3 4 4 3 3 4 3 5 5 5 5 4 5 4 4 4}"

import re

print [[ int(i) for i in  x.split(" ")] for x in [ match for match in re.findall("\{([\d ]+)\}", m_string)] ]
```

results in:

> [[3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3,
>   2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3,
>   3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3,
>   3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3,
>   3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
>   4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3,
>   3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4,
>   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4], [2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3,
>   4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2,
>   2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3,
>   2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
>   3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3,
>   3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3,
>   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4,
>   3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
>   4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3,
>   4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5,
>   4, 5, 4, 4, 4]]